# Get feature from list

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, point, list

I've done this:

```
while (feature != null)
            {
                if ((feature.get_Value(feature.Fields.FindField("NAME")) != null) && (feature.get_Value(feature.Fields.FindField("NAME")).ToString() != " "))
                {
                    itemList.Add(feature.get_Value(feature.Fields.FindField("NAME")).ToString());
                }
                feature = featureCursor.NextFeature();
            }
```

Now I have a listBox with fields values. How can I get a feature back by its name?

The idea was:

1. create a list with objects names,
2. find feature on map, clicking by its name on list.

Features (objects) represent as points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to use a query to get back the corresponding feature:

```
IQueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilterClass();
queryFilter.WhereClause = "NAME = '<featureName>'";

using (ComReleaser comReleaser = new ComReleaser())
{
  ICursor cursor = table.Search(queryFilter, true);
  comReleaser.ManageLifetime(cursor);
  IRow row = null;
  while ((row = cursor.NextRow()) != null)
  {
    String name = row.get_Value(nameIndex);
    IFeature featureBack = row as IFeature;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

IQueryFilter is the best option for your problem.You can put your name value in the whereclause of the queryfilter and thereby you can get the desired feature.

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IQueryFilter queryFilter = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.QueryFilterClass();
queryFilter.WhereClause = "NAME LIKE 'LIGHT_POLE';     
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ICursor cursor = featureLayer.Search(queryFilter, false);
```